# Call code per click button

Tags: php

can someone help me and tell me where I can put my xml code to be called when it's clicked on this button. Thank you all for the answer. Attached is my xml code and code for the button.

```
<p class="woocomerce-FormRow form-row">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce'); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Register', 'woocommerce'); ?>" />
</p>


<?php
//rest/customers 
$xml = "<customer><activation-code>" . rand(100000, 999999) . "</activation-code>
    <area-code-id type=\"integer\"></area-code-id>
    <billing-failure-date type=\"datetime\" nil=\"true\"/>
    <created-at type=\"datetime\"></created-at>
    <email>" . $current_user->user_email . "</email>
    <first-name>" . $resultVorname->value . "</first-name>
    <id type=\"integer\"></id>
    <language-id type=\"integer\">2</language-id>
    <last-name>" . $resultNachname->value . "</last-name>
    <npvr-limit type=\"integer\" nil=\"true\"/>
    <npvr-quota type=\"integer\">360000</npvr-quota>
    <other-than-stb-devices-limit type=\"integer\">1</other-than-stb-devices-limit>
    <phone>" . $resultTelefon->value . "</phone>
    <pin>" . rand(1000, 9999) . "</pin>
    <pvr-limit>NO_LIMIT</pvr-limit>
    <secondary-pin>" . rand(1000, 9999) . "</secondary-pin>
    <status>enabled</status>
    <stb-devices-limit type=\"integer\">1</stb-devices-limit>
    <updated-at type=\"datetime\"></updated-at>
    <uuid></uuid> 
    <external-id nil=\"true\"/>
    <npvr-quota-used type=\"integer\">1</npvr-quota-used>
    <npvr-limit-used type=\"integer\">1</npvr-limit-used>
    <area-code-external-id nil=\"true\"/>
    <language-external-id nil=\"true\"/>
    <address-attributes>
    <city>" . $resultOrt->value . "</city>
    <street>" . $resultStrasse->value . "</street>
    <postal-code>" . $resultPostleitzahl->value . "</postal-code>
    <province-id>119</province-id>
    </address-attributes>
    </customer>";

$url = 'https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx/rest/customers';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', 'Authorization: Basic QTFDVjVsaGl5d1d2NXh3UWJ0OFE6'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
//print $data;
//var_dump($data);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
//print_r($arr['id']);



if (curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The code should be executed when it is clicked on the registration button, so I want to send this xml to the server immediately.

and this is from the whole action where I noticed that this button is called..

```html
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

   <p class="woocomerce-FormRow form-row">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"/>
   </p>
   <?php
```

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working?

Comment: I tried to put in the button code, but it does not show me any error in executing the sending of this code, so I ask for help, I would like it at least to show something when it clicks to know that it works at all.